# Creating mongodb database user in Java using spring data mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I need to create a mongodb database user in a Spring boot application using spring data mongodb. I will be creating this user as part of application startup.
I could not find any reference for doing this using spring data mongodb.
Is that possible by using Spring data mongodb?

Comment: why cant you create the user directly in mongo and ask spring boot to use that user...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the past and I end up by creating the user before the context load, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        createMongoDbUser();

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    private void createMongoDbUser() {
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(HOST, PORT);
        MongoDatabase db =  mongo.getDatabase(DB);
        Map<String, Object> commandArguments = new BasicDBObject();
        commandArguments.put("createUser", USER_NAME);
        commandArguments.put("pwd", USER_PWD);
        String[] roles = { "readWrite" };
        commandArguments.put("roles", roles);
        BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject(commandArguments);
        db.runCommand(command);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Spring-data-mongodb will create the db all by itself if it can't find it, when declaring your mongo-db factory.

For instance, I declare my db-factory in xml using the following:

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongofactory" dbname="dbNameHere" mongo-ref="mongo" />
```

I did not have to create it myself, it was created by spring-data-mongodb upon firing may app the first time.